# Find max value of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I'm trying to find the max value of an array

```
function highestNumb(arr) {
  Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
}

highestNumb([12,4,6,0]);
```

Why do I keep getting *undefined*?

Comment: `return Math.max.apply(Math, arr);`

Answer (score 2):

Need to return from the function

```js
function highestNumb(arr) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
}

alert(highestNumb([12,4,6,0, 44]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Any function should *return* result:

```
function highestNumb(arr) {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
}

highestNumb([12,4,6,0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! It's very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are returning a result from your function:

```
function highestNumb(arr) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
}

console.log(highestNumb([12,4,6,0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code don't return anything so undefined

```
function highestNumb(arr) {
return Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
}
highestNumb([12,4,6,0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function highestNumb(arr) {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
}
```

You have no return statement so it returns undefined by default.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get the max value from an array, probably using `Math.max()` would be "the right way", here are some:

```
const numberArray = [5, 7, 2, 9, 20, 5];

// Using Math.max()
Math.max(...numberArray);

// Using reduce()
numberArray.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b));

// Using sort()
numberArray.slice().sort((a, b) => a < b)[0]
```

You could use any of those in a function like this:

```
const someFunction = nArr => Math.max(...nArr);
// Or
function someOtherFunction(nArr) { 
    return Math.max(...nArr);
}

console.log(someFunction([5, 7, 2, 9, 20, 5])); // 20
console.log(someOtherFunction([5, 7, 2, 9, 20, 5])); // 20
```

- [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)
- [... spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
- [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)